# How can I echo Woocommerce shipment tracking in an email template?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In the Woocommerce Shipment Tracking  plugin they use:

```
<?php echo esc_html( $tracking_item['tracking_number'] ); ?>
```

to get the shipping tracking number. How can use something similar directly in a Woocommerce email template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with and it works!

```
<?php 
$order_id = $order->get_order_number();
$tracking_items = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_wc_shipment_tracking_items', true );

foreach ( $tracking_items as $tracking_item ){
    echo esc_html( $tracking_item['tracking_number'] );
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated version for WooCommerce 3.0+:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $queue_item->order_id );
$tracking_items = $order->get_meta( '_wc_shipment_tracking_items', true );

if ( count( $tracking_items ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $tracking_items as $tracking_item ) {
        $tracker = esc_html( $tracking_item['tracking_number'] );
    }
}
```