# How to echo Woocommerce shipment tracking URL in email?

Tags: php, woocommerce, cpu-word

I already found this topic here: [How can I echo Woocommerce shipment tracking in an email template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518957/how-can-i-echo-woocommerce-shipment-tracking-in-an-email-template) This is working but in my case I want to display the tracking link instead of the tracking number. We want to display this info on a specific position. The plugin code shows me this:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $tracking_item['formatted_tracking_link'] ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php _e( 'Track', 'woocommerce-shipment-tracking' ); ?></a>
```

In the documentation of the plugin is says, that I can access the data with the key `tracking_link`

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shipment-tracking/#section-9

So then I tried to access the data with that.. But its always empty.. but the infos are there.. becasue when I use `tracking_number` instead of `tracking_link` then I get the right tracking number of the order.

**Update:**
Based on the new infos, I have to do a workaround here because the "tracking_link" value is empty.

```
// Test - Output tracking code - 3
$tracking_items = $order->get_meta('_wc_shipment_tracking_items');

if( ! empty($tracking_items) ) { 
    foreach ( $tracking_items as $data ){
        echo '<a href="https://www.post.ch/swisspost-tracking?formattedParcelCodes='.<?php echo esc_url( $data['tracking_number'] ); ?> . '" target="_blank">'. sprintf( __('Track (number %s)', 'woocommerce-shipment-tracking' ), $data['tracking_number'] ) .'</a>';
        print_r($data);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:** Don't use the order number… Better use the defined `WC_Order` object like:

```
$tracking_items = $order->get_meta('_wc_shipment_tracking_items');
```

or using the order ID *(from the defined WC_Order object)* like:

```
$tracking_items =  get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_wc_shipment_tracking_items', true );
```

So based on [Shipment Tracking documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shipment-tracking/#section-9) provided link, try:

```
$tracking_items = $order->get_meta('_wc_shipment_tracking_items');

if( ! empty($tracking_items) ) { 
    foreach ( $tracking_items as $data ){
        echo '<a href="https://www.post.ch/swisspost-tracking?formattedParcelCodes='. esc_url( $data['tracking_number'] ) . '" target="_blank">'. sprintf( __('Track (number %s)', 'woocommerce-shipment-tracking' ), $data['tracking_number'] ) .'</a>';
        // print_r($data); // For testing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have a syntax error.. https://ibb.co/SrX5N1b all what I try does not work to fix this syntax error..         echo '<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $data['tracking_link'] ); ?>" target="_blank">' . sprintf( __('Track (number %s)', 'woocommerce-shipment-tracking' ), $data['tracking_number'] ) .'</a>';

Comment: ahh.. this is ugly.. it seems like, that the tracking link is empty.. but this is very strange.. because the link is actaully there.. I have to do a workaround. => https://www.post.ch/swisspost-tracking?formattedParcelCodes={trackingcode} this is the tracking URL and I now have to insert the tracking_number instead of the placeholder.

Comment: I just made a update of my post. What is the best way to combine the hardcoded URL + the tracking number?

Comment: [custom_tracking_link] is always empty. That's why I guess I have todo a workaround with the hardcoded URL + the tracking number. This would work fine.. but i have to combine both. (See updated post)

Comment: I do not understand why the </a> has a problem: https://ibb.co/6Dg6GH6

Comment: I just updated the code above in my question.

Comment: Thanks! Works! :))